# Lua metatable variable

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have some question for Lua metatable...
This is my code:

```
setmetatable(t1, mb)
setmetatable(t2, mb)
print("t1:", getmetatable(t1))
print("t2:", getmetatable(t2))
mb.__index = mb

print(t1.a)
t1.a = 2
print(t2.a)
mb.a = 3
print(t1.a)
print(t2.a)
```

and this is output:

```
t1:     table: 00D62D88
t2:     table: 00D62D88
1
1
2
3
```

Output shows me that t1 and t2 has same metatable mb(same address),I think t1.a and t2.a are mb.a,they are same variable.
But when give t1.a a new value,t2.a no change.,when give mb.a a new value,t3 is change!
Could someone explain what happen for it?

Answer (score 2):

That's how `__index` works.

If `t` has a metatable `m` with an `_index` entry pointing to a table `s`, then reading `t.a` resolves to `s.a`, *when* `t.a` *is nil*.